# Display custom Windows phone dialog

Tags: windows-phone-7, dialog

I'm developing a windows phone app and I want to pop up a dialog when a button is clicked.That dialog will be custom and contain some information. In android it is simple, could I do it in windows phone?

Comment: are you want to show some text on your custom dialog

Comment: Yes some text and close dialog button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of popup control create a UI element of your need and add as child to the popup window and make the isopen property to true to show the dialog. For more information look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup%28v=vs.95%29.aspx